# How to create discrete color brush?

Tags: wpf, brush

To have brush: [image]
I'm currently write this code:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Path=offset1}" Color="{Binding Path=g1}"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Path=offset1}" Color="{Binding Path=g2}"/> <!-- -->
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Path=offset2}" Color="{Binding Path=g2}"/> <!-- -->
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Path=offset2}" Color="{Binding Path=g3}"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

That's what a kind of cheat! I'm wondering is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems pretty legit to me

Comment: yep, that's the way the cookie crumbles.